# What is the difference between 书面演讲 and 带稿发言?

Tags: word-choice, culture

Mainstream media report:当地时间11月16日上午，国家主席习近平向在旧金山举行的亚太经合组织工商领导人峰会发表题为《同心协力 共迎挑战 谱写亚太合作新篇章》的书面演讲。

As far as I know, almost all Chinese leaders are reading from a prepared script except the earlier leaders like Jiang Zemin江泽民 and Zhu Rongji朱鎔基, when they deliver a speech in public either in or outside China.So I do not understand why 书面演讲 is mentioned specially here.

At first, I thought 书面演讲 was a presentation of a piece of writing without the physical presence of the speaker, as in some of the academic workshops, where their papers are put up on the bulletin board or posted line because the time is too short for each speaker to talk fully.

So it is actually 带稿发言(read out of a provided text or on prompt),and is there any difference?

Comment: 发言 is more informal, like a short speech or comment made during a conference, where lots of people are making similar speeches. 演讲 is more formal, and I think 书面 is more of a filler word that makes it sound more formal.

Comment: is there any difference? 没有区别